# Shared iCloud album returns all assets slowly

Tags: swift, icloud, shared, phphotolibrary

Created async function that, once user has given permission and selected shared album, runs to gather all assets in a shared album.  It is slow and I'm not sure what I am doing wrong.

```swift
struct AlbumAsset: Identifiable {
    
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let index: Int
    let album: String
    let file: String
    let name: String
    let image: Image
    let asset: assetType
    let imageType: PHAssetMediaType
    let imageWidth: Int
    let imageHeight: Int
    let createDate: Date
    let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    
    init(id: String = UUID().uuidString, index: Int, album: String, file: String, name: String, createDate: Date, asset: assetType, image: Image, imageType: PHAssetMediaType, imageWidth: Int, imageHeight: Int, location: CLLocationCoordinate2D){
        self.index = index
        self.album = album
        self.file = file
        self.name = name
        self.createDate = createDate
        self.asset = asset
        self.image = image
        self.imageType = imageType
        self.imageWidth = imageWidth
        self.imageHeight = imageHeight
        self.location = location
    }
    
}

func getAlbumAssets(albumName: String) async -> Array<AlbumAsset> {
        
    let settings = appSettings()

    var albumAssets: [AlbumAsset] = [AlbumAsset]()
    var albumAssetsResult = PHFetchResult<AnyObject>()
        
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
    
    let albumCollection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: fetchOptions)
    if albumCollection.firstObject != nil {
    
        albumAssetsResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(in: albumCollection.firstObject!, options: nil) as! PHFetchResult<AnyObject>
        
        let requestImageOptions = PHImageRequestOptions()
        requestImageOptions.version = .current // .original // .unadjusted
        requestImageOptions.resizeMode = .exact : .fast // .none
        requestImageOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat // .opportunistic // .opportunistic //fastFormat
        requestImageOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        requestImageOptions.isSynchronous = true

        let requestVideoOptions = PHVideoRequestOptions()
        requestVideoOptions.version = .current // .original
        requestVideoOptions.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat // .mediumQualityFormat // .fastFormat // .automatic
        requestVideoOptions.isNetworkAccessAllowed = true
        
        let imageManager =  PHImageManager() // PHCachingImageManager()

        var imageRequestWidth = 200
        var imageRequestHeight = 200
        let imageSize = CGSize(width:imageRequestWidth,height:imageRequestHeight) // PHImageManagerMaximumSize 
        
        var albumAssetsRecords: [PHAsset] = []
        albumAssetsResult.enumerateObjects{(object: AnyObject!, count: Int, stop: UnsafeMutablePointer<ObjCBool>) in
                
                if object is PHAsset{
                    let asset = object as! PHAsset
                    
                    albumAssetsRecords.append(asset)
                    
                    var mediaimage = asset.mediaType == .image ? Image("iva") : Image("vai")
                                        
                    let index       = count
                    let album       = albumName
                    let file        = asset.fileName
                    let name        = asset.localIdentifier
                    let cdate       = asset.creationDate
                    let mediaasset  = assetType.image(type: "")
                    let imageType   = asset.mediaType
                    let imageWidth  = Int(CGFloat(asset.pixelWidth))
                    let imageHeight = Int(CGFloat(asset.pixelHeight))
                    let location    = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 0.0, longitude: 0.0)

                    if asset.pixelWidth > imageRequestWidth && asset.pixelHeight > imageRequestHeight { //found that some photos were zero in size
                        imageManager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: imageSize, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: requestImageOptions, resultHandler: { (image, info) in
                            if image != nil {
                                mediaimage = Image(uiImage: image!)
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    
                    let newAsset = AlbumAsset(index: index, album: album, file: file, name: name, createDate: cdate!, asset: mediaasset, image: mediaimage, imageType: imageType, imageWidth: imageWidth, imageHeight: imageHeight, location: location)
                    albumAssets.append(newAsset)
                    
                }
                
            }
            
            return albumAssets
        }
        
    }
    return []
}
```

Return of array has multiple attributes which are used in LIST or other foreach on view.

Other function uses similar but only pulls collection of shared albums.